# Conectar EntityFrameworkCore com base de dados Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

Bom dia pessoal, estou dando inicio nos meus estudos com o EntityFrameworkCore e notei que ele só se comunica bem com SqlServer, alguém conhece algum plugin ou coisa do tipo que faça essa conexão e trabalhe decentemente com Oracle?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada na página de suporte do EF?  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/providers/

Comment: Parece que já tem, mas aparece a desagradável informação "pago" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a página de suporte dos provedores do EF (em 12/06/2018), na seção "Provedores futuros":

> A equipe de .NET da Oracle anunciou que pretende liberar um provedor
>   próprio para o EF Core 2.0 aproximadamente no terceiro trimestre de
>   2018. Consulte as declarações de direção para .NET Core e Entity Framework Core da Oracle para obter mais informações. Encaminhe
>   quaisquer dúvidas sobre este provedor, incluindo o cronograma de
>   lançamento, para o Site da Comunidade Oracle.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/providers/

E tem esse no `NugGet`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore/

Comment: Massa cara, obrigado.